# Retrieve Saved Function Calls, MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I stored a function in MongoDB that executed a few mongodb atomic functions in a row so I didn't have to keep typing them out.

I since have forgotten what I named that function.

Does anyone know how to retrieve a list of saved functions within a MongoDB instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the list of saved function  in server side try using

```
  > db.system.js.find();
The _id field holds the name of the function and is unique per database.
The value field holds the function definition
```

Answer (score 0):

db.system.js.find() should give you the full list and source code, just project the _id field to get the name.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/